# Pass a std::vector v to the ctor of a class which needs to access v during the whole life time of a corresponding instance

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to pass a `std::vector<double> v` to the constructor of a class `A` which needs to access `v` during the whole life time of a corresponding instance. Since `v` is assumed to be huge, I don't want to make a copy of `v`.

We could do the following: *Option 1*:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::vector<double> const& v)
        : m_v(v)
    { }

private:
    std::vector<double> const& m_v
};
```

This might be a suitable option if we could guarantee that the life time of the referenced `v` object is at least as long as the life time of the corresponding instance of `A`. But it's unlikely that we can guarantee that.

*Option 2:*

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> v)
        : m_v(v)
    { }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> m_v;
};
```

This option has no life time issues. However, I'm not sure if this is really best practice. So, how should we do that?

Comment: Do you need to keep the vector accessible outside the object too?  Or is it no longer needed by anything except the new `A` instance?

Comment: You should use `shared_ptr<*const* vector<double> >`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you cannot guarantee that the life time of the referenced `v` object is at least as long as the life time of the corresponding instance of `A`,
- and if you don't want to copy `v`,

then `shared_ptr` is the way to go. It *is* considered best practice.

For example, see [Guru Of The Week 91, by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Note: `shared_ptr`will extend `v`'s lifetime, while `weak_ptr` won't - you may lose `v` (in a safe way) during `A`'s life. Whether you need one or the other depends of your use case.

Answer (score 3):

If the vector has to stay alive for the whole lifetime of an instance of A I would go for option 2, otherwise I would consider std::weak_ptr<std::vector<double>>

Answer (score 2):

> This might be a suitable option if we could guarantee that the life time of the referenced v object is at least as long as the life time of the corresponding instance of A. *But it's unlikely that we can guarantee that.*

(emphasis mine) suggests there is more work to do on the design. Either your class controls the lifetime of the vector or it depends on it. Which is it? This should be clear in any documentation and descriptions of the interface.

**IF** you stipulate that `A` depends on the vector being available, then it's acceptable to demand that in the interface:

```
A::A(const std::vector<double>& v)  // Demand that v outlives A
: _v(v) {}
```

**IF** you stipulate that `A` will share the vector with other objects, then demand it in the interface:

```
A::A(std::shared_ptr<const std::vector<double>> pv) // demand shared ownswership
: _pv(std::move(pv)) {}
```

**IF** you stipulate that `A` will actually control the lifetime of the vector (and thereafter own it) then either `move` the vector into it or `move` a unique_ptr into `A`:

```
// call with auto a = A(std::move(v));
// or auto a = A(std::vector<double>(...));
A::A(std::vector<double> v)  // demand ownership or copy
: _v(std::move(v)) {}

// or

A::A(std::unique_ptr<const std::vector<double>> pv) // demand ownership
: _pv(std::move(pv)) {}
```

part of 'best practice' is using interface definitions to provide guarantees to clients and make demands of them.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I'm not sure if this is really best practice. So, how should we do that?

```
auto make_huge_vector()
{
    return std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>( /* ... */ );
}
```

Current best practice (forcefully extends lifetime of the vector, if needed):

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> v): v_{ std::move(v) } {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> v_;
};

// client code:
auto v = make_huge_vector();
A a{v};
```

Comment: I would make `A`'s constructor accept a lambda of `make_huge_vector` type, and call it in the constructor.

Comment: that will violate the "law of demeter": your class needs to use a pointer to a vector - not a pointer to a vector and a functor for creating it. Further more, you may be forced to define an identity lambda (lambda that returns it's argument) to use the class, if you already have the vector in client code.

Comment: Then it's back to the very first comment under the question: is shared ownership truly necessary, or should the object take exclusive ownership of the vector? If the answer is no and yes, then it makes more sense to generate the vector in the class. In order not to expose vector generating code to the class, DI is the way to go.